# Having trouble getting the new v3 router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Having a little trouble getting the new v3 router.  How do I get it?  I assume I have to update my package.json and run a npm update.

Comment: Any concrete error message or a concrete unexpected behavior? Yes, you need to update package.json and update. This might help http://plnkr.co/edit/33NMwe7QCz5iwr492Vk4?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package.json you have to add dependency of

`"@angular/router": "^3.0.0-alpha.3"`

Next install the module. Now you just have to modify a bit the system.config.js file as there is no umd for router yet. Remove 'router' from ngPackageNames and add this to packages array:

```
'app': {
   main: 'boot.js',
   defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

That's all abot the config. Now you should be ready to go! Please refer to the [Angular 2 > Developer Guide > Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) to find out how to use it in the code

Plese notice, that at this very moment current version of other Angular2 packages is "2.0.0-rc.2" (maybe besides @angular/forms that is in "0.1.0")

Comment: thanks!  now I am having an issue compiling...getting this everywhere with an existing project.  Do I need to update something else?

node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts(80,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.